# Jersey Google app engine - Resource not found

Tags: google-app-engine, jersey

I am deploying a sample app in Google App Engine that uses Jersey. However when I try to do a GET or POST to the REST resource I get a - 404 NOT FOUND error. Looks like I am missing something.

REST resource code:

```
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

    @Path("/stream")
    public class StreamingResource {
        private static final Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(FacebookStreamingResource.class.getName());

        @POST
        @Path("/callback")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String putStreamData(JSONObject jsonEntity) {
            return jsonEntity.toString();
        }

        @GET
        @Path("/get")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String getStreamData() {
            return "Get successful";
        }
    }
```

Here is the web.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>services</param-name>
                <param-value />
            </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>JerseyWebApplication</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.vbv.fb</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>JerseyWebApplication</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/stream/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

I have included the following jars:

asm-3.1.jar
jersey-client-1.12.jar
jersey-core-1.12.jar
jersey-json-1.12.jar
jersey-server-1.12.jar
jersey-servlet-1.12.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.jar
jackson-xc-1.7.1.jar

App Engine SDK version is 1.7.0

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed the  in web.xml from /stream/* to /* it works :)